# How to install objective-c header files on ubuntu OS?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to import `#import<objc/object.h>` in my code. But it is giving me an error "No such file or directory compilation terminated.". Is this because I didn't install the header files or because I didn't included the headers files path to the compiled object library.